# Get an OAuth2 access token failed with error message "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized"

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, cas, pingfederate

I am writing OAuth client in JAVA to acquire OAuth token from Central Authentication Service (PingFederate). As this client is standalone utility, there is no application server behind it.

I am trying to achieve : ***A standalone JAVA client should acquire OAuth token from PingFederate it should allow for some scope, ex. TEST_READ. Once I have access token, I will pass it to resource provider.***

So, as per the PingFederate document such standalone client should use the Grant Type=Resource Owner Password Credentials and to acquire Oauth token POST request should contains username/password and client id and secret.

When I attempted the same, I received error in response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 09:04:50 GMT, Content-Security-Policy: referrer origin, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, Pragma: no-cache, Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT, Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8, WWW-Authenticate: basic realm="PF AS Token Endpoints", Set-Cookie: PF=zVXrZpsAmWwrrVkzgltJZ4;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly, Transfer-Encoding: chunked] org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@68c9133c
```

To dig more into it, I checked PingFederate audit.log where I found the log: `AS| failure| | invalid_client: client_id value doesn't match HTTP Basic username value| 0`

### Here is my JAVA client code

```
package com.auth;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class OAuth2Client {

    public static final String GRANT_TYPE = "grant_type";
    public static final String CLIENT_ID = "client_id";
    public static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "client_secret";
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
    public static final String BASIC = "Basic";
    public static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token";
    public static final String SCOPE = "scope";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getAccessToken());
    }

    public static String getAccessToken() {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                "https://localhost:9031/as/token.oauth2");
        String clientId = "OAUTH-CLIENT-TEST";
        String clientSecret = "OAUTH-CLIENT-TEST-SECRET";
        String scope = "TEST_READ";
        String username = "testuser";
        String password = "test#001Pass";

        List<BasicNameValuePair> parametersBody = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair(GRANT_TYPE, "password"));

        parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair(CLIENT_ID, clientId));
        parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair(CLIENT_SECRET, clientSecret));
        parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SCOPE, scope));

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = null;
        String accessToken = null;
        try {
            //post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametersBody, HTTP.UTF_8));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametersBody));

            post.addHeader(AUTHORIZATION,
                    BASIC + " " + encodeCredentials(username, password));
            post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            response = client.execute(post);

            int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (code >= 400) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Could not retrieve access token for user: " + username);
            }
            Map<String, String> map = handleJsonResponse(response);
            accessToken = map.get(ACCESS_TOKEN);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return accessToken;
    }

    public static String encodeCredentials(String username, String password) {
        String cred = username + ":" + password;
        String encodedValue = null;
        byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(cred.getBytes());
        encodedValue = new String(encodedBytes);
        System.out.println("encodedBytes " + new String(encodedBytes));

        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedBytes);
        System.out.println("decodedBytes " + new String(decodedBytes));

        return encodedValue;

    }

    public static Map handleJsonResponse(HttpResponse response) {
        Map<String, String> responseMap = null;
        String contentType = response.getEntity().getContentType().getValue();
        try {
            responseMap = (Map<String, String>) new JSONParser()
                    .parse(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not parse JSON response");
            throw e;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("********** Response Received **********");
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : responseMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("  %s = %s", entry.getKey(),
                    entry.getValue()));
        }
        return responseMap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The grant type "password" requires the user's (or: Resource Owner's) credentials to be passed in the POST parameters (`username` and `password`) instead of the `Authorization: basic` header.

Comment: Thanks Hans for reply, when I have attempted username and password instead of Authorization header, commented Add authorization header line and added parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username)); parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
Now this is giving error:HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.
Whereas, pingfed audit.log=AS| failure| | invalid_grant: No validator mappings configured

FYI. for OAuth client configuraiton along with client_id and secret Grant types=ROPC and refresh token mentioned.

Comment: That's a PingFederate configuration issue, not a code issue anymore. You need to configure a Resource Owner Credentials Mapping for the Password Credentials Validator that you want to use to validate the username/password provided.

Comment: Thank you Hans, the code changes with the PingFederate configuration that you have suggested worked fine for me!